# Rewrite URL empty values in query string - Double slashes, Optional Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have looked around quite a bit and tried myself and could not sort it out.

This is the URL before applying rewrite :

```
http://example.com/job-search/?searchText=GOOGLE+INC.&searchCity=Enter+US+City+or+Zipcode&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=Enter+Job+Title+%2F+Role+Name
```

This is the URL after below rewrite rules are applied  :

```
http://example.com/job-search/GOOGLE-INC./Enter-US-City-or-Zipcode/14/search/Enter-Job-Title
```

I have the below rules in .htaccess. It works well, when I have the URL like above with all the fields.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /job-search/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?searchText=([^\s&]+)&searchCity=([^\s&]+)&searchYear=(\d+)&action=([^\s&]+)&searchJobTitle=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?searchText=$1&searchCity=$2&searchYear=$3&action=$4&searchJobTitle=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The rewrite fails, when It gets empty values. The rules do not work and I get the below URL.

```
http://example.com/job-search/?searchText=GOOGLE-INC.&searchCity=&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=
```

Of the three parameters ( searchText or searchCity or SearchJobTitle ), at a time, only one of the parameters will be having a value and other two will have blank values. Also, just want to ensure, when the user types the home page URL like  http://example.com/job-search/ , it should not fail  ( I tried something and it failed ) . Would like to avoid  double slashes as well, when they are empty.

Below is the output I would like to see :

E.g when searchCity and SearchJobTitle are empty, the output URL should look like

```
http://example.com/job-search/GOOGLE-INC./14/search
```

When searchText and searchCity are empty and searchJobTitle value is 'Applicaton-Engineer', the output URL should look like

```
http://example.com/job-search/14/search/Application-Engineer
```

Can you please help me get the right rule ? Appreciate your help !

Comment: If parameters can be optional, you should probably rethink how you want these URLs to look like taking into account some of them can be blank

Comment: @JonLin currently, I am checking in PHP, if they are blank or null and doing respective actions. I have added the URLs structure, if they are to be blank for clarify.

Comment: No, I mean the URL as in: `/A/B/C/D/E/F`, if any one of those are optional, it'll look like: `/A/B/D/F`, then how are you supposed to tell which one was supposed to be "C" or "E"? Or that they are actually blank?

Comment: @JonLin, Good point, I was thinking that when I submit the form, the REQUEST object will mention which value it was assigned to and which comes as blank, so when I read the values, it would be blank. I see your point, when someone is directly accessing with the URL, rather than submitting the form. I am thinking. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /job-search/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?searchText=([^\s&]+)&searchCity=&searchYear=(\d+)&action=([^\s&]+)&searchJobTitle=\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?searchText=([^\s&]+)&searchCity=([^\s&]+)&searchYear=(\d+)&action=([^\s&]+)&searchJobTitle=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?searchText=$1&searchCity=$2&searchYear=$3&action=$4&searchJobTitle=$5 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?searchText=$1&searchYear=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, it works for scenario one, when the search text is not blank and others are blank. But it fails when the searchCity is not blank and other two are blank. I get this URL http://example.com/job-search/?searchText=&searchCity=milwaukee&searchYear=14&action=search&searchJobTitle=

Comment: You should not merge multiple problems in same question. I have provided you an answer on how to handle blank values. Try to build a rule for other combinations yourself, if you face problems then please open a new question.

Comment: Understand, Thanks ! will try to build.